# Why multiset uses operator< of the object it stores?

Tags: c++, stl, operator-overloading, multiset

On storing My custom objects on multisets the object's class requires to have a operator< .

I want an explaination of the internal workings of multiset, so that I can understand why operator< is required.

Because, some of objects cannot be compared by < or > operator. Does that means I cannot store them in multiset.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't require `<` as such, it requires a *strict weak ordering*.

In short, if the function `before` is the ordering relation, then the following must hold:

- For all `x`, `before(x, x)` is false
- For all `x` and `y`, if `before(x, y)` is true then `before(y, x)` is false
- For all `x`, `y`, and `z`, if `before(x, y)` is true and `before(y, z)` is true, then `before(x, z)` is true

The `<` relation is the default because it is already defined for many types, in a way that fulfills the strict weak ordering conditions.
(Exercise: verify that it does.)

The ordering relation is used to establish an equivalence relation between elements; if `a` is not ordered before `b`, and `b` is not ordered before `a` - that is, `!before(a,b) && !before(b, a)` - then they are considered equivalent.
Equivalent elements belong to the same "multi-element" of the multiset (note that, unlike with `std::set`, equivalent elements can occur more than once).
The multiset itself is ordered according to the ordering relation.

Even if you can't define a "strictly less than" relation for a type, you can usually define a "should be ordered 'before' for this particular purpose" relation.

Answer (score 1):

Multiset is a sorted container.

It needs to use a comparator to compare elements.

Using the types `operator<` is the default, but you can use other comparators, in that case the type of the comparator needs to be passed as template paramter:

```
template<
    class Key,
    class Compare = std::less<Key>,    // <<----
    class Allocator = std::allocator<Key>
> class multiset;
```

`std::less<Key>` is the default and uses `Key::operator<`.

> I want an explaination of the internal workings of multiset, so that I can understand why operator< is required.

Actually no, you don't need that. A multiset is sorted and uses `operator<` by default because it is specified to do so. If you do care about the implementation you can of course look at it, but it won't give you much insight on *why* `<` is used. It is defined in the header `<set>`.

Comment: Under normal circumstances, `<` and `>` would be the only operators that could check for both equality and ordering, no?

Comment: @super I dont understand what you mean. `Compare` can be almost anything, the only restriction is that it is a strict weak ordering.

Comment: @super containers typically do not use equality but equivalence which is `!(a < b) && !(b < a)` (and thats not necessarily the same as `a == b`)

Comment: @super eg `unordered_set` used `==` (equality), which can be a bit surprising when you are used to equivalence via `<`, but as it is unordered it doesn't need `<` and requiring `==` is the lesser constraint

Comment: I can't disagree with any of that. Still, it seems to me like there is a good reason to use `<` or `>` as the default. It's intuitive since it would allow odering and *equivalence* checks.

Comment: @super didnt say that you disagree, just trying to understand what you mean. You mean: Why not eg `<=` ? That would work too but you'd always need to check `a <= b` and `b <= a` to see if `a < b`

Comment: I mean that OP is asking why `operator<` is required. To me it seems there is some what of a reason as to why.

Comment: @super I have problems to imagine how else one would sort elements. To know if `a` comes before `b` you look at `a < b`. As the other answer explains, that doesnt have to be the "traditional" `<`, but we can still call it `<`

Comment: Exactly. I think an answer could benefit from including that since I don't assume that it is obvious to everyone.

Comment: @super thanks for your input, I think I'll try to improve the answer (later)